# How do regular and unit regular elements interact with the direct sum.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is some (possibly noncommutative) ring. I say that an element $a\in R$ is regular if there is some $x\in R$ such that $a=axa$. I say it is unit regular if I also require $x\in U(R)$, the units of $R$. Suppose $S$ is some other ring, how do the regular and unit regular elements interact with the direct sum operation? Suppose we know what the regular and unit regular elements of $R,\,S$ are; can we say anything about the regular and unit regular elements of $R\oplus S$? Suppose all the regular elements of $R,\,S$ are unit regular, is the same true for $R\oplus S$? My guess is no, but are there certain conditions upon which this is true? I was thinking of applying this to the case where $R=\mathbf{Z}[G]$, $G$ finite, and $S=\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why isn't $(r,s)$ unit regular iff $r$ and $s$ are both unit regular? The same statement should hold for regular elements as well.

Comment: Well perhaps this is where I am at a bit of a loss. I have been reading through Lam's Crash Course on Stable Range and noted the theorem that a right $R$ module $M$ is internally cancellable iff $reg(End(M))=ureg(End(M))$ where $reg(-)$ and $ureg(-)$ are the sets of regular and unit regular elements respectively.

Comment: Now Lam provides an example $R=\mathbb{R}[x,\,y,\,z]$ where $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Moreover, $R$ and $R^2$ are internally cancellable, and so $reg=ureg$, but $R^3$ is not! In fact, if we let $P=ker(R^3\to R)$ then $P\oplus R\cong R^3\cong R^2\oplus R$ and $P\not\cong R^2$. So clearly $reg(R^3)\neq ureg(R^3)$.

Comment: It seems straightforward that $(u,u')$ is a unit iff both $u$ and $u'$ are units in their respective rings, and therefore $(a,b)(u,u')(a,b)=(a,b)$ implies $a$ and $b$ are unit regular. Conversely given $aua=a$ and $bu'b=b$ you have your unit $(u,u')$. I have a hard time seeing where this breaks down...

Comment: According to what you've written, we should expect $R$, $M_2(R)$ to have equal sets of reg and ureg, but $M_3(R)$ to have differing sets. Where does $R\times R\times R$ come in?

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, I mean that the cited example above refers to statements about *the modules* $R_R, R^2_R, R^3_R$ and their endomorphism rings, but never refers to the ring product $R\times R\times R$.

Comment: I agree with you that I can't see where this breaks down. But according to the theory M internally cancellable iff $reg(End(M))=ureg(End(M))$ surely we get a problem. So look at the free $R$-module (Defined above) of rank 1; then this has endomorphism ring $End(R)\cong R$. Similarly, $End(R^2)\cong R^4$ and $End(R^3)\cong R^9$. Now, since $R,\,R^2$ are internally cancellable, $reg(R)=ureg(R)$ and $reg(R^4)=ureg(R^4)$. By your argument (which I would have thought is right), surely that means $reg(R^9)=ureg(R^9)$ and $R^3$ is internally cancellable. A contradiction. Or am I being really stupid?

Comment: It's OK, I think we're homing in on the solution. It's true that $End(R^3)\cong R^9$ *as $R$ modules* but not *as rings* which is  the issue still. The ring $R^4$ and $R^9$ aren't  endomorphism rings of any of the modules we are talking about: $ureg(R^9)$ and $ureg(M_3(R))$ are totally different.

Comment: Ah I see, then I now realise where my mistakes lie. Perhaps I need to look into what $End(-)$ is as a ring. I just assumed that these were the same as for modules.

Comment: Cool. I only wish I had time to read that paper in detail someday.